# Regular expression to capture command

Tags: regex, regular-language

How can I make a regular expression that matches `clear abc` and then I capture `abc` which can vary?

The command `clear` will always be the same and the structure of the string will always be `clear ?` where `?` can vary.

I guess it is something like `/^clear \w$/` where `^` makes sure that the string starts with `clear`. But I want to make sure that it only matches something that has two words where the first word is `clear`, so that it doesn't match, for instance, `clear ab cd ef`. The word after `clear` can both be 1 character and multiple characters, but it can never start with a number.

## Edit

From the answers, I got the regex `/^clear [a-zA-Z]\w*$/`.

What if the variable after clear can be things like `a` and `ab` but also `f(x, y)`. Would it then just be `/^clear [a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z() ]*$/`, so it also accepts `(`, `)` and space ()?

Can it be a little more robust by making sure it has the design `f(...)` if it ever contains parentheses, so I don't end up matching e.g. `f)dsada`?

Comment: Which *specific* regex syntax? BRE, ERE, PCRE, re2? `\w` isn't honored everywhere.

Comment: I don't know. I use it in a JavaScript website

Answer (score 2):

> The word after clear can both be 1 character and multiple characters, but it can never start with a number.

You can use this regex:

```
/^clear [a-zA-Z]\w*$/
```

- `[a-zA-Z]` ensures it start with an alphabet
- `\w*` after will match 0 or more word characters after first letter

If `POSIX` character classes are available then use:

```
/^clear [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*$/
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` isn't guaranteed to do the intended things in all locales; better to use `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: It seems I cannot use `POSIX`, but the first regex worked :D In javascript, I can use `regex.test(str)` to validate, but how do I capture the variable value after clear?

Comment: If the var adter *clear* is a valid identifier, you'd better use `[a-zA-Z_]\w*` to match it.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it's ok. Otherwise, I will create a new question

Comment: @Jamgreen: Based on edited question, you can try this regex: `/^clear [a-zA-Z_][\w (),]*$/`

Comment: But then it also accepts `clear a b`. I guess I need to check if the structure is `?(?)` where both `?` can be anything, and if it is, then I will accept space and comma.

Comment: Will [`^clear [a-zA-Z_](\([^)]*\)|\w*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qU2gF0/1) this work in that case?

Comment: I have to capture everything. Both the first character and the rest. But otherwise it looks correct!